# How can I return to my loop after an exception?

Tags: python, http, request, urllib

I have the code below:

```
import urllib.request
import json

flag_servidor = 0
flag_salva_txt = 0
numero = 0

#codigo para verificar se há conexao como servidor e caso nao
#haja ele criar um arquivo txt com as infos

while 1:
    try:
        url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://IP/CAMINHO/get_infos.php')
        x_ = url.read()
        y_ = json.loads(x_.decode('utf-8'))
        get_turno_ = y_["turno"]
        print(get_turno_)

        #salva as infos do txt dentro do banco de dados
        if flag_salva_txt == 1: #significa que temos infos para serem salvas
            arquivo = open('novo-arquivo1.txt', 'r')
            for linha in arquivo:
                linha = linha.rstrip()
                valor = linha.split(";")
                print(valor[0])
            flag_salva_txt = 0
        continue
    except Exception as e:
        print("Servidor indisponível.Erro:", e)
        if flag_salva_txt == 0:
            #após salvar txt 
            flag_salva_txt = 1
            numero = numero +1
            arquivo = open('novo-arquivo'+str(numero)+'.txt', 'w')
            arquivo.write('nova linha;123;1pop' + '\n')
            arquivo.close()
        continue
```

The problem is that: when an exception happened for the first time it shows me message error but when it happens for second time my code stop running and doesn´t show anything.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's hard to follow the logic of your code here... Also, what do you mean "it stops running and doesn't show anything"? There is no way the `while 1:` loop can just stop.

Comment: What exception(s) are you expecting to catch here? You are probably hurting yourself by casting too wide a net by using the generic `Exception` which is probably obscuring other errors in your code. Try focusing on a more narrow exception first while allowing others to be raised so you can see tracebacks for them and debug as necessary. (In fact, as currently written, neither of the `continue` statements in your code are actually necessary--if you catch an exception without re-raising it then execution should continue after the `except:` block).

Comment: I guess that the program is arrested in a try function, it trys to make a connection but how can not connect it doens´t leave there

Comment: Still, what is your program actually supposed to do? The way I see it, it gets some data over HTTP, prints it and does nothing further with it... and if there had been an error during this process, it writes some static data into a new file, then sets a flag to read a file after the next HTTP request... I can't make heads or tails of it :)

Comment: @Iguananaut the function try has a delay?

Comment: @AKX I want to try connecation, verify ih has connection all the time before execute some functions

Comment: "try" isn't a function. It's a "block-level statement"--all the code in the "block" under the `try:` statement is always executed each time you go through the loop, and if an exception occurs in *any* of those lines the execution will jump to the `except:` block and skip any of the remaining code in the `try:`.  You will probably solve your own problem by first experimenting with some simpler code by trying to write a [Complete, Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, try localizing the `try/except` just immediately around the code that you expect might fail.  For example put `except:` immediately after `urllib.request.urlopen` or maybe after trying to parse the JSON, in order to minimize the amount of code your `except:` is covering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not quite crystal clear about what your program is supposed to do, but maybe something like this helps.

I refactored your program to a separate function to get the data, and printing it out (or whatever you like to do) is in the main loop.

In addition, to not hit the server as fast as your script can, there's a delay of 5 seconds between every request, successful or not.

```py
import datetime
import time
import urllib.request
import json


def get_turno():
    url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://IP/CAMINHO/get_infos.php")
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode("utf-8"))
    return data["turno"]


while True:
    try:
        turno = get_turno()
    except Exception as exc:
        print("Retrieving turno data failed: {}".format(exc))
    else:
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
        print("Time: {} - Turno: {}".format(current_time, turno))
    time.sleep(5)
```